# How to rearrange x-position of significance lines in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr, significance, rstatix

Please find the data that I need to visualize [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AP3gE4c9QKgQf4j_joEgVyXx44IG_BEK/view?usp=sharing). I want to reveal if there is any variable that is significantly different than the reference variable. I draw the barplot, list the variables, which will be compared with each other, make the statistics and draw the significance lines as you see below. It is all good up to this point.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(here)
library(readxl)
library(ggforce)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsignif)
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)

data <- read.csv(here("data", "data.csv"), sep = ";")

# List the variables to be compared with each other in pairwise comparison
my_comparisons <- list( c("%0", "250 µg/ml"), c("%0", "100 µg/ml"), c("%0", "50 µg/ml"), c("%0", "25 µg/ml"))

#Statistics
stat.test <- data %>%
  t_test(OD ~ Material_Concentration, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni", comparisons = my_comparisons) %>%
  add_significance("p.adj")

stat.test

# add significance
stat.test <- stat.test %>%
  add_xy_position(x = "Material_Concentration")

#plot the data
p <- ggplot(data, aes(Material_Concentration, OD, colour = Material_Concentration))+          
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "col", aes(fill = Material_Concentration), show.legend = FALSE)+
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2, show.legend = FALSE)+
  xlab("Treatment Concentrations")+
  ylab("Average OD")+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(color="red", size=40, face="bold.italic", hjust = 0.5), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20, angle = 45, hjust = 1), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15))+
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p.adj.signif")
  
p
```

[Positioning of significance lines are correct in this image, however I want to rearrange the variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h252p.jpg)

However, when I rearrange the positions of variables on x-axis, by using `scale-x-discrete` the x-positions of significance lines do not change.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(here)
library(readxl)
library(ggforce)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsignif)
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)

data <- read.csv(here("data", "data.csv"), sep = ";")

# List the variables to be compared with each other in pairwise comparison
my_comparisons <- list( c("%0", "250 µg/ml"), c("%0", "100 µg/ml"), c("%0", "50 µg/ml"), c("%0", "25 µg/ml"))

#Statistics
stat.test <- data %>%
  t_test(OD ~ Material_Concentration, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni", comparisons = my_comparisons) %>%
  add_significance("p.adj")

stat.test

# add significance
stat.test <- stat.test %>%
  add_xy_position(x = "Material_Concentration")

#plot the data
p <- ggplot(data, aes(Material_Concentration, OD, colour = Material_Concentration))+          
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "col", aes(fill = Material_Concentration), show.legend = FALSE)+
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2, show.legend = FALSE)+
  xlab("Treatment Concentrations")+
  ylab("Average OD")+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(color="red", size=40, face="bold.italic", hjust = 0.5), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20, angle = 45, hjust = 1), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("250 µg/ml", "100 µg/ml", "50 µg/ml", "25 µg/ml", "%0", "%10"))+
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p.adj.signif")
  
p
```

[Positioning of significance lines are not correct in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp30R.jpg)

How can I solve this problem? I would be really glad if you may reveal my mistake.

Thank you

Comment: I would suggest changing your data by making your `x` column a factor with the levels in the order that you want. Something like `data$Material_Concentration <- factor(data$Material_Concentration, levels = c("250 µg/ml", "100 µg/ml", "50 µg/ml", "25 µg/ml", "%0", "%10"))` immediately after reading in the data. If you need more help than that, please make your example [reproducible, as described at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by sharing a small amount of sample data.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It worked perfectly. It is the first time I ask a question on this platform. I will take care of reproducibility next time.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).